# package introduction for using speech recognition in java

Tags: java

i want to create an  application using inbuilt java package's which should support me in speech recognition

("Actually Thinking to develop app like in movie "her" which talks to human as and give response with AI")

Comment: Speech Recognition, you mean?

Comment: yap Speech Recognition .. sorry i made a mistake there

Comment: it is easy to write code in vb .. if i can use vb  programs in java then it wold be more better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Java Platform package yet for speech recognition.  However, there's at least one opsn-source project for speech recognition with a simple Java API ... http://voce.sourceforge.net/ (see also its dependencies).